# How to include all docs in ElasticSearch Aggregation and avoid sum_other_doc_count > 0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

ES is not mainstream for my work, and there's one behavior I'm not able to correct. I have a fairly simple aggregation query:

```json
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "request_type": "some_type"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "carrier_name.keyword": "some_carrier"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_date": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "date",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "carrier_total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html is that not all documents are included in the aggregation. Indeed, depending on the query section, I do see in the results "sum_other_doc_count" : with values greater than zero.

My question: is there a way to construct the search so that all docs are included? The number of documents is fairly small, typically under 1k,

Thanks in advance,
Reuven

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentaion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size),

> `size` defaults to 10
>
> `from` + `size` can not be more than the `index.max_result_window` index
> setting, which defaults to 10,000.

In your case the documents are fairly small, nearly 1k, therefore 1k results can be easily retrieved.

> The size parameter can be set to define how many term buckets should
> be returned out of the overall terms list. By default, the node
> coordinating the search process will request each shard to provide its
> own top size term buckets and once all shards respond, it will reduce
> the results to the final list that will then be returned to the
> client.

So a request is to be made to include top 1000 documents, in the field date.

...

```json
"by_date": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "date",
    "order": {
      "_term": "asc"
    },
    "size": 1000
  }
}
```

...

**The higher the requested size is, the more accurate the results will be, but also, the more expensive it will be to compute the final results**

To know more about this, you can refer this [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Comment: Thanks Bhavya - that was what I needed - marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `size` of the terms agg from the default `10` to a large-ish number:

```
...
    "by_date": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "date",
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        },
        "size": 1000           <-----
      }
...
```